# How to convert an iterator to a string in c++11? a boost solution is ok too

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, iterator

this is How I print out the items and it works:

```
for(list<Record>::iterator it=record_list.begin(); it != record_list.end(); it++)
   {
      cout << "" << *it << endl;
   }
```

now, how to convert *it to a string.

Comment: It depends what a `Record` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### With Boost

```
boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(*it);
```

### Without Boost

```
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << *it;
std::string str = ss.str();
```